# htaccess rewrite for query string for multiple pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would really appreciate some help about .htaccess rewrite for query string for multiple pages.

The original page is /products.php?q=anything&type=cat

- anything is dynamic value
- cat is static value

And I would like to know how can I rewrite above url to /category/anything/page.html

I try to find a solution from several online sources but it seems after I place a rewrite rule, it return to products.php each time.

Thank you

Comment: so you want to rewrite .php file as .html file? How do you think that it's even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: Question is unclear as `category` and `page` are not even in original URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming that you are always going to send the user to "page.html" and the only variable is "anything". If that's true, this should work:

`RewriteRule ^category/(anything)/page.html /products.php?q=$1&type=cat`

It will make the webserver send the query for `/category/something/page.html` to `/products.php?q=something&type=cat`

Comment: Thank you

But it doesn't work to get q to display a null value not q.

In my words is set:

category to replace a products.php
?q=anything-I-declare replace with /anything
&type=cat replace with page.html